# why surround document.write with curly braces

Tags: javascript

I've just seen a `document.write()` surrounded by curly braces.

```
<script type="text/javascript">{document.write("<img src'...' />")}</script>
```

This seems to work fine. It doesn't produce any errors when I replicate it in JSBIN. What is the purpose?

Comment: None at all. It only defines a superfluous but harmless block statement.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: Your closing `)` is in the wrong place, btw.

Comment: @Bergi Typed it quickly while in a meeting. Thanks for catching! Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused that it is a an object literal. But the compiler not finding `:`(and value) and instead finding `}` inteprets it as a block statement and nothing more than that.

Block statements help you in grouping your statements.

[Block Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Comment: I'd really prefer not to see it called "scope" since that has meaning when discussing languages, and JS explicitly does *not* have anything like a "block scope". Especially when there's a section in the link called "No Block Scope" :/

Comment: @DaveNewton had used statement everywhere except the line :)